# Python authentication via X.509 client certificate (.cer file) and comparison with Java

Tags: java, python, ssl, python-requests, x509certificate

I am currently trying to replicate a java tool in python that allows users to proceed to some REST APIs calls to an application in the cloud.
With this Java tool, you can either create script that utilizes a traditional user/password-type credentials or a .cer certificate.

I could easily recreate the user/password authentication in Python with the requests library.

But for the certificate way, it is another story. I have been looking for a solution to do in Python for days but it looks like the .cer certificate is not sufficient for Python.

I am pretty new in SSL/TLS so I might not have understood all the concepts behind it but it seems that in addition to the .cer certificate (that is a PEM format, containing the public key and the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- -----END CERTIFICATE-----" part), I would need to get the private key. Which is weird as the Java tool does not need that at all.

If someone can enlighten me on that topic, that would be fantastic !

Thanks,

Chris

Additional info :

As Steffen asked (I really thank you for your help), I will be more precise.
I am trying to perform this request with Python :

req = requests.request('GET','https://api.YXZ.com/1/9/whatever/', cert='certificate.pem')

I have this error message :

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.XZY.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1/9/whatever (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, u'[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2603)'),))

I would believed it is due to my certificate as I can perform this request with a basic authentication.

I could see what is in the certificate thanks to the following command :

openssl x509 -text -inform DER -in certificate.cer

Which gives me a text with the following format :

Data:
Signature Algorithm:
  Issuer
  Validity:
  Subject Public Key
Signature Algorithm :
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: i feel requests library must be supporting some ssl/tls. see docs.

Comment: also, see https://hpbn.co/transport-layer-security-tls/. a great resource to learn about ssl/tls

Comment: Thx Vasif. I'll have a deep look to it

Answer (score -1):

> ... I would need to get the private key. Which is weird as the Java tool does not need that at all.

You always need a private key for a certificate if you want to authenticate yourself, i.e. for server certificates at the server side and for client certificates at the client site. If you have only the certificate but not the private key you can only verify authentication of the peer but not authenticate yourself. This is independent of Java, Python ...

If you had a working client certificate with Java then you had also the matching private key in your key store but probably did not export it to be used by Python. Alternatively there was no client certificate at all but you only checked the server certificate for validity (w/o needing the private key). In this case you should not try to use this certificate as client certificate in Python too.
But, it is hard to tell exactly what is the problem w/o having any code and/or detailed error messages.

Comment: Thx Steffen, I added additionnal info if it can help.

Comment: @ChrisKeo: the additional information only show that you are trying to use a certificate for client authentication but that this certificate has no private key - which is needed as I explained. It is not clear if the original code really used a client certificate at all - in which case you would need to export the private key from the original key store too and not only the certificate.

Comment: So if I understand well, I need to export the private key from the original keystore (I have to find out how to do so) and then I will be able to create a thorough .pem file, combining the private key and the certificate I already have. Is that correct ?

Comment: I know it's a been a long time (I found the answer a big while ago) but thank you again for that answer. With subsequent research, I realized that the authentication I was trying to replicate was not using a standard PKI architecture.